# How can I add a site title refiner?

Tags: 2013, search

We have hundreds of subsites, one for each project.
Inside each subsite, different document libraries and content types.

Sometimes when searching, we get matches from different subsites.

How can I add a refiner for the subsite name? Is there a managed property for this? Or does it need to be a custom refiner?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the solution:

- Go to **Search Center Site** > **Site Settings** > click **Search Schema** under Site Collection Administration
- Type refinablestring in the Managed property text box
  [image]
- Click on the **RefinableString02**( you can select any other refinablestring) and Edit it
- Add **ows_SiteName** in the Mappings to crawled properties and Give a unique Alias name. I have put MainSiteName2
  [image]
- Click OK
  [image]
- Go to **Central Administration** > click Manage service applications under Application Management
  [image]
- Click on Search Service Application
  [image]
- Click on Search Schema under Queries and Results 
  [image]
- Type refinablestring in the Managed property text box(Same as before)
- Click on the RefinableString02 and Edit it
- Add **ows_SiteName** in the Mappings to crawled properties.(This time Alias name does not require)
  [image]
- Click OK
  [image]
- Now Click on the Content Source under Crawling
- Start Full Crawl and let it complete
  [image]
- After Full crawl completion go to the Search Center site and Navigate to your search page. In my case results.aspx
- Edit the Page and Edit the Refinable WebPart
  [image]
- Click on the **Choose Refiners...**
  [image]
- Add RefinableString02 as shown below:
  [image]
  [image]
- Write Site Name in the Display name text box.
  [image]
- Click OK Button
- Click OK in the Refinement Web Part Pannel.
  [image]
- Publish the page
  [image]

Enjoy!!!

Answer (score 4):

SiteTitle is a Managed Property in search but it is not set to be "refinable" by default.  Go to Central Admin > Service Applications > Search Service and then Search Schema.  Search for "SiteTitle" in the managed properties.  You'll see that the property is set to "Queryable" and "Retrievable" but not refinable.  Edit the Managed Property and set it to be Refinable - Yes, Active.  Run a full crawl.  Now the property can be shown as a refiner.

To set up the Refiner (I'm assuming you already have a Refinement web part on the page), edit the web part and "Choose Refiners".  Now that you've done the first step, you should see "SiteTitle" under the list of available refiners.

Answer (score 1):

I will admit I haven't tried this yet, but I was looking at the instructions for adding refiners here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/11/11/how-to-add-refiners-to-your-search-results-page-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Took a look at the available mappings (as part of my own question I'm trying to answer) and noticed in the SharePoint category there is a property of ows_Site which may be what you are looking for.