# how to adjust search result page sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, search-results, sharepoint-on-prem

When I use search search in SharePoint, and type something to search for.
I get a long list of documents. And on the left side i have options to filter

- Filter by document type
- Filter by author
- Filter based upon a change in a date-span

What i like to have is an option to filter results by (sub)sites as well.
Any ideas on how to add that ?.

Comment: Something like this? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn794243.aspx

Comment: Here is the answer: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/109409/how-can-i-add-a-site-title-refiner